# std::filesystem::canonical and std::filesystem::absolute are not working

Tags: c++, filepath, c++20, boost-filesystem, std-filesystem

I am using C++2a standard Visual Studio 2019 as compiler for the code.

```
std::filesystem::path parentPathX(argv[0]);
std::cout << "Running: " << argv[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Path wise: " << parentPathX.string() << std::endl;
std::filesystem::path parentPath = std::filesystem::canonical(parentPathX.parent_path());
String parentPath1 = parentPath.string();
//findAndReplaceAll(parentPath1, " ", "^ ");
std::cout << "Parent Path: " << parentPath1 << std::endl;
```

be it canonical or absolute, it doesn't give out the output required.
I don't pass the entire command as the argument, but `cd` till that folder and run the command, which means, [image]

Output with `std::filesystem::canonical`

```
C:\Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release>MWPixelAggr.exe G:\Work\abc\M-4591.tif DN wgs84 G:\Work\abc\TestMP.xlsx 3
Running: MWPixelAggr.exe
Path wise: MWPixelAggr.exe
Is Absolute? 1
Parent Path:
```

As you can see in the image, I don't have any output of for the canonical code.

Output with `std::filesystem::absolute`

```
C:\Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release>MWPixelAggr.exe G:\Work\abc\M-4591.tif DN wgs84 G:\Work\abc\TestMP.xlsx 3
Running: MWPixelAggr.exe
Path wise: MWPixelAggr.exe
Is Absolute? 1
Parent Path:
```

As you can see in the image, I don't have any output of for the absolute code.

---

---

Input:
A file which I'm running. Basically the /. Convert it into a canonical path/absolute path.

I tried absolute too and it also gave me the same output.

---

Update:
I tried the same code using boost filesystem, I got some output but not correct.

[image]

`C:\dasfsa/dsfafsa/sdfsa/a.exe` Which is unusable. I can manually convert that one backslash but I don't know if it's some kind of esoteric feature or a bug and if it's a bug, I don't know where else it'll change that slash and how.

Output with `boost::filesystem::canonical`

```
C:\Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release>MWPixelAggr.exe G:\Work\abc\M-4591.tif DN wgs84 G:\Work\abc\TestMP.xlsx 3
Running: MWPixelAggr.exe
Path wise: MWPixelAggr.exe
Is Absolute? 1
Parent Path: C:/Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release
```

As you can see in the image, I don't have any output of for the boost::canonical code.

Comment: Please post your command outputs as text not images

Comment: In Visual Studio the current working directory is usually not the location of the executable.

Comment: I should've gotten some path, right? Append the file to the `cwd` or something.

Comment: you're running canonical/absolute on an empty path, what do you expect?

Comment: Won't it be the `.` current folder?

Comment: Although, I did find a solution and it worked with `boost::filesystem::absolute(parentPath.parent_path())`

Comment: `std::filesystem::path` doesn't represent a physical location, so as far as it's concerned the parent of `"MWPixelAggr.exe"` is `""`. While boost::filesystem seems to be working differently I'm not sure it's really a good solution. You probably want to get the absolute path first and then the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `boost::filesystem::absolute` and it worked. I got the required output.

code:

```cpp
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
```

```cpp
fs::path parentPathX(argv[0]);
fs::path parentPath = fs::absolute(parentPathX.parent_path());
std::cout << "Is Absolute? " << parentPath.is_absolute() << std::endl;
String parentPath1 = parentPath.string();
//findAndReplaceAll(parentPath1, "/", "\\");
std::cout << "Parent Path: " << parentPath1 << std::endl;
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release>MWPixelAggr.exe G:\Work\abc\M-4591.tif DN wgs84 G:\Work\abc\TestMP.xlsx 3
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

C:\Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release>MWPixelAggr.exe G:\Work\abc\M-4591.tif DN wgs84 G:\Work\abc\TestMP.xlsx 3
Is Absolute? 1
Parent Path: C:\Users\Tarun Maganti\source\repos\MWPixelAggr\Release
```